# Is there any way to get a drop down list of time zones?

Tags: php, timezones

How can I access the time zone list in drop down similar to the time zone selector in the settings? I want the time zones to be similar to the exact list of the what is in the settings page.

I searched the site but I didn't find a question related to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Enter [`wp_timezone_choice()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone_choice/):

```
<select>
    <?php echo wp_timezone_choice( 'UTC' ) ?>
</select>
```

Make sure to check out the documentation link, but the parameters are:

> `$selected_zone (string)` (Required) Selected timezone.
>
> `$locale (string)` (Optional) Locale to load the timezones in. Default
> current site locale.